# How does any application work?

Tags: web-applications, interface, frontend, backend

This may seem like a very silly question. I kind of know how to program both a frontend and backend, but never built a complete application myself before. So the question is, how does a complete application work? i.e. how does frontend and backend connect/link when both are written in different languages? When I build an objective-C app, I see the user interface, but how do I connect the UI with let's say a backend analytics proram.

Thanks.

Comment: [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is the usual method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to understand the client server model, the client sends a request to the server and server responds to the request. Now this client can be any thing like a web-browser, an application(android, IOS, IOT etc. whatever that can make a web request).

Most of the applications requires HTTP requests only.

When the server receives the HTTP request it locates the appropriate document based on the path and parameters passed and returns it as a response. HTTP response is required to have a particular format, it must look like this:

```
HTTP/[VER] [CODE] [TEXT]
Field1: Value1
Field2: Value2
...Document content here...
```

The first line shows the HTTP version used, followed by a three-digit number (the HTTP status code) and a reason phrase meant for humans. Usually the code is 200 (which basically means that all is well) and the phrase "OK". The first line is followed by some lines (in the form of keys and values) called the header, which contains information about the document. The header ends with a blank line, followed by the document content. This is a typical header:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: Netscape-Communications/1.1
Date: Tuesday, 25-Nov-97 01:22:04 GMT
Last-modified: Thursday, 20-Nov-97 10:44:53 GMT
Content-length: 6372
Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<HTML>

...followed by document content...
```

We see from the first line that the request was successful. The second line is optional and tells us that the server runs the Netscape Communications web server, version 1.1. We then get what the server thinks is the current date and when the document was modified last, followed by the size of the document in bytes and the most important field: "Content-type".

The content-type field is used by the browser to tell which format the document it receives is in. HTML is identified with "text/html", ordinary text with "text/plain", a GIF is "image/gif" and so on. The advantage of this is that the URL can have any ending and the browser will still get it right.

An important concept here is that to the browser, the server works as a black box. Ie: the browser requests a specific document and the document is either returned or an error message is returned. How the server produces the document remains unknown to the browser. This means that the server can read it from a file, run a program that generates it, compile it by parsing some kind of command file or (very unlikely, but in principle possible) have it dictated by the server administrator via speech recognition software. This gives the server administrator great freedom to experiment with different kinds of services as the users don't care (or even know) how pages are produced.

Finally your question: it does not matters which programming language you are using, the only thing matters is the format of request and response. In your case you can use a JSON based API to send data to your application in JSON format.

That's so less I can write. I guess it will help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of techniques you can employ but mainly for web applications you are communicating over the HTTP protocol.  With http alone you can send small payloads of data using a common format such as json or XML.

There are still more ways that are built on top of these concepts like websockets, Ajax, rest, and RPC (remote procedure calls).

This is a huge topic but you must definitely expose yourself to many of these techniques to be a well rounded developer.  And I don't mean on the waistline.